# Why these mocks are not resetting?

Tags: testing, jestjs, next.js, mocking, nock

I am making app with Nextjs and Jest and React Testing Library for testing. I use [nock](https://github.com/nock/nock) for mock axios responses.

My tests:

```
axios.defaults.adapter = require('axios/lib/adapters/http');

describe('Contacts component', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        nock.disableNetConnect();

        nock(BACKEND_URL).defaultReplyHeaders(nockReplyHeaders).options('/api/user').reply(200);
        nock(BACKEND_URL).defaultReplyHeaders(nockReplyHeaders).get('/api/user').reply(200, RootUserJson);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        // mock resetting
        nock.restore();
    });

    it('loads first contacts list', async () => {
        // these mocks works fine
        nock(BACKEND_URL)
            .defaultReplyHeaders(nockReplyHeaders)
            .options(`/api/friendship/friends/${RootUserJson.id}?page=1`)
            .reply(200);
        nock(BACKEND_URL)
            .defaultReplyHeaders(nockReplyHeaders)
            .get(`/api/friendship/friends/${RootUserJson.id}?page=1`)
            .reply(200, ContactsFirstPageJson);

        render(
            <Contacts />
        );

        // some expects..
    });

    it('loads empty list and show empty component', async () => {
        // these mocks not returns EmptyJson, it return json from first test
        nock(BACKEND_URL)
            .defaultReplyHeaders(nockReplyHeaders)
            .options(`/api/friendship/friends/${RootUserJson.id}?page=1`)
            .reply(200);
        nock(BACKEND_URL)
            .defaultReplyHeaders(nockReplyHeaders)
            .get(`/api/friendship/friends/${RootUserJson.id}?page=1`)
            .reply(200, EmptyJson);

        render(
            <Contacts />
        );

        const emptyComponent = await screen.findByText('No contacts, add some friends');
        expect(emptyComponent).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```

Mocks resetting not working. Mock from second tests returns json from first test. I want to reset mock after each **it()**. Please for help.

Comment: The beforeEach() is run before each it() block, and the afterEach() after the it().  You do not have the actual tests, so not sure what you are doing with the nock().  Typically you are mocking the call so it does not happen and provide the response.  It is almost like saying `const response = 'This is the result text';` and then testing that.  However, the mock is in place of the real call, so your test calls your function which uses axios to retrieve the results, but instead of axious, your mock is called to return the results. Without the tests, not overly sure what you doing.

Comment: Calls which are mocked in test are called in useEffect of tested component...